# Workaround for session rate-limiting/throttling in LogRocket

Tags: performance, frontend, monitoring, apm, logrocket

Since LogRocket doesn't have an inbuilt way to rate-limit the number of sessions, is there a way to do it by ourselves? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with is to ignore specific users and environments so we can basically ignore test automation users and local development. Otherwise we end up using 4k sessions a week before even getting production sessions.